# Duplicate entry for 'name of dag' for key in 'dag_id'

Tags: python, airflow

I'm running a dag that triggers another dag two times with different payloads using TriggerDagRunOperator.

The first one starts to run, but the second always fails saying:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'external_dag-2021-11-01 00:00:00.000000' for key 'dag_id'"
```

Both TriggerDagRunOperator have different execution_dates and "reset_dag_run" set to true:

```
x = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="x_external_dag",
    trigger_dag_id="external_dag",
    python_callable= pass_args_for_x,
    execution_date="{{ execution_date }}",
    reset_dag_run = True
)
y = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="y_external_dag",
    trigger_dag_id="external_dag",
    python_callable=pass_args_for_y,
    execution_date="{{ ds }}",
    reset_dag_run = True
)
```

I have run out of ideas on how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards!

Comment: Does x and y is in different dag or in same dag?    
The error suggests that you are trying to execute a single dag for the same exact execution time.   I don't think `reset_dag_run` will reset while 1 is *currently* running.

Comment: Hey @lautaropacella, I was wondering if my answer below was helpful to you. If so, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is related to the fact that boths *DagRuns* are being triggered with the same `execution_date`. `"{{ ds }}"` and `"{{ execution_date }}"` are different representations of the same value, different types, `str` and `DateTime`. Also note that the `{{ execution_date }}` variable will soon be [deprecated](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

To solve the error, try not defining `execution_date` during Tasks definition. Docstrings don't specify it but, the default value is actually `None`. Taking a look at the [execute() method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/dc4dcaa9ccbec6a1b1ce84d5ee42322ce1fbb081/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun.py#L120) of the **TriggerDagRunOperator**, you will find that when is not defined, the `execution_date` of the DAG that is being triggered is set to `timezone.utcnow()`.

Following this path, I think you won't need to set `reset_dag_run = True` either. I haven't tested it myself, but should be:

```py
x = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="x_external_dag",
    trigger_dag_id="external_dag",
    python_callable= pass_args_for_x

)
y = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="y_external_dag",
    trigger_dag_id="external_dag",
    python_callable=pass_args_for_y
)
```

Let me know if it worked for you.